# Perl search and replace: replacing end of line replaces beginning to line too

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file [data.txt] with the following data

```
a,b,c,d,e
e,f,g,h,i
j,k,l,m,n
```

I use the following perl command to replace the end of line with some text.

```
perl -pi -e 's/$/ X/g' data.txt
```

However, my file reflects the following (it replace the start of line too)

```
a,b,c,d,e X
 Xe,f,g,h,i X
 Xj,k,l,m,n X
```

This is unexpected, can anyone point out if I am missing anything obvious?

Cheers
Saurabh

Comment: Do not use `g` flag, remove it, see https://ideone.com/UIyN5M

Comment: Why does the g flag have this effect?

Comment: It has been discussed in some SO questions. The point is that perl regex supports matching zero width strings (locations) before each char and end of string, and then it can re-test the chars after these empty strings (it is important as it makes it possible to split strings using lookarounds). Also, `$` matches a location before the final newline, and at the very end of the string. Well, the logic must be: regex must match end of line only once, else, there may be unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You could also rewrite it to:

```
perl -i -ple '$_ .= " X"' data.txt
```

which is easier to read in this case. I think. The `-l` option removes `\n` from each line first and then adds it after (right before it `-p`rints) so you basically dont have to think about `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

When `/m` isn't used, `$` is equivalent to `(?=\n\z)|\z`.

As you can see, it can match at two different locations. For example, in the following, it can match at position 9 (`(?=\n\z)`) and at position 10 (`\z`).

```
01234567890   <- positions
a,b,c,d,e␊
```

Solution: Remove the `/g` to only match the first of the two.

```
perl -pe's/$/ X/'
```

Solution: Remove the line feeds and match at the end of the string.

```
perl -ple's/\z/ X/'    # «$» would work as well as «\z», but I like to say what I mean.
```

Solution: Remove the line feeds and just use concatenation.

```
perl -ple'$_.=" X"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(.+)$/$1X/' data.txt
```

EDIT: Removed g as suggested. Also, with g removed, the solution can be simplified to

```
perl -pi -e 's/$/X/' data.txt
```

Comment: What about empty lines, should they not end in X? And you still don't need the `/g` modifier.

Comment: Depends on what the user wants, he can modify the regex to cover empty lines as well. My answer solved the problem as specified, but I agree that covering empty lines makes sense.

Comment: They were needed when the substitution was with g, but without g, the expression can be simplified. Will add a note.